# Call nested methods on object only if it exists using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I currently have a `user` object, which has a `currentRoom()` method on it, which might sometimes not exist or return `null`.

If the `currentRoom()` method returns something, I then need to call a `messages()` method on that. If nothing is returned from either, I’d like to return a default empty array `[]`.

I’d like to tackle this functionally using Ramda, so it’s neat and reusable. Currently, my (non Ramda) code looks like this:

```
const user = Users.findOne({ username: params.id })
const room = (user.currentRoom && user.currentRoom() || {})
const messages = (room.messages && room.messages() || [])
```

Some kind of logic I was thinking was to pass in the list of required methods, along with the default result if nothing comes out of it.

```
/* getMessages(defaultIfNull, methodsArray, object) */

getMessages([], ['currentRoom', 'messages'], user)
```

Basically something a bit similar to `pathOr`, but for methods on objects.

Comment: Btw, the default value for `room` should be `{}` rather than `[]`

Comment: Good spot. Fixed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess I'd use the `List` monad like an `Option`:

```
const getRoom = user => "currentRoom" in user ? [user.currentRoom()] : [];
const getMessages = room => "messages" in room ? room.messages() : [];

const allTogether = R.compose(R.chain(getMessage), R.chain(getRoom), R.of);
console.log(allTogether(Users.findOne({ username: params.id })));
```

Comment: Now the empty array is ambiguous within the code: It may either mean non-deterministic choice or exception. I don't know if this is a good advice.

Comment: @ftor I've never seen arrays used for exceptions? The empty array means having no choice. I do agree that this isn't the cleanest solution (surprised by the many upvotes), maybe a `Option<Array<Message>>` would have been better; unfortunately Ramda does not come with a builtin option type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a point-free solution using just Ramda. First, we define a `withDefaults` function which will set up `currentRoom` and `messages` methods in objects which these methods are undefined.

```
var withDefaults = R.pipe(

    // if don't have `currentRom` add a
    // `currentRom` function that returns an empty object
    R.unless(
        R.hasIn('currentRoom'), 
        R.assoc('currentRoom', 
            R.always({}))), 

    // if don't have `messages` add a
    // `messages` function that returns an empty array
    R.unless(
        R.hasIn('messages'), 
        R.assoc('messages', 
            R.always([]))))
```

This function filters the object setting up methods if needed. Usage example.

```
var user = withDefaults(getById(id))
```

Next, define a getter functions to get rooms and messages from objects. `invoker` is the central piece of this snipet, it returns a function that invokes a method. See http://ramdajs.com/docs/#invoker

```
var getCurrentRoom = R.invoker(0, 'currentRoom')
var getMessages = R.invoker(0, 'messages')
```

Above code can be used as following.

```
var userWithRoom = withDefaults({
        currentRoom : function () {
            return {
                number : '123'
            }
        }
    })

var userWithMessages = withDefaults({
        messages : function () {
            return [
                'get lunch'
            ]
        }
    })

var userWithAll = withDefaults({
        currentRoom : function () {
            return {
                number : '123'
            }
        },
        messages : function () {
            return [
                'get lunch'
            ]
        }
    })

var userWithNone = withDefaults({})
```

All together

```
var withDefaults = R.pipe(
    R.unless(
        R.hasIn('currentRoom'), 
        R.assoc('currentRoom', 
            R.always({}))), 
    R.unless(
        R.hasIn('messages'), 
        R.assoc('messages', 
            R.always([]))))

var getCurrentRoom = R.invoker(0, 'currentRoom')
var getMessages = R.invoker(0, 'messages')

// examples

var userWithRoom = withDefaults({
        currentRoom : function () {
            return {
                number : '123'
            }
        }
    })

var userWithMessages = withDefaults({
        messages : function () {
            return [
                'get lunch'
            ]
        }
    })

var userWithAll = withDefaults({
        currentRoom : function () {
            return {
                number : '123'
            }
        },
        messages : function () {
            return [
                'get lunch'
            ]
        }
    })
```

Now lets test above code using `console.log` to see if our solution works as expected

```
console.log(getCurrentRoom(userWithRoom))
console.log(getCurrentRoom(userWithMessages))    
console.log(getCurrentRoom(userWithAll))    
console.log(getCurrentRoom(userWithNone))

console.log('---')

console.log(getMessages(userWithRoom))    
console.log(getMessages(userWithMessages))    
console.log(getMessages(userWithAll))    
console.log(getMessages(userWithNone))
```

The output should be:

```
{ number: '123' }
{}
{ number: '123' }
{}
---
[]
[ 'get lunch' ]
[ 'get lunch' ]
[]
```